# How to run multiple node js services using command line on local and hereko server.?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I have multiple services in my node js app as below

```
.git
 domain
 public
 view
 .gitingore
 service1.js
 service2.js
 service3.js
 package.json
 package-lock.json
 Procfile
 README.md
```

`service1.js` code

```
var port = process.env.PORT_SERVICE1 || 8001;
 .....
 .....
 .....
```

`service2.js` code

```
 var port = process.env.PORT_SERVICE2 || 8002;
 .....
 .....
 .....
```

`service3.js` code

```
var port = process.env.PORT_SERVICE3 || 8003;
 .....
 .....
 .....
```

Currently i am running above3 services on windows as below ..

```
 set PORT_SERVICE1 = 8001
 set PORT_SERVICE2 = 8002
 set PORT_SERVICE3 = 8003
```

and opening 3 different command promt to run all services

```
 node service1.js
 node service2.js
 node service3.js
```

I want to configure same in heroko Procfile file. but not able to set it?

How to set different port for all services in node js and run them all ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using [PM2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io)

It allows you create complex config file, that will start all your applications with configs you've provided.

Here's an example of how to run multiple applications using config file

```js
module.exports = {
  apps: [{
      name: 'sevice1',
      script: './services/sevice1',
      watch: true,
      env: {
        NODE_ENV: 'development',
      },
      env_production: {
        NODE_ENV: 'production',
      },
    }, {
      name: 'sevice2',
      script: './services/sevice2',
      watch: true,
      env: {
        NODE_ENV: 'development',
      },
      env_production: {
        NODE_ENV: 'production',
      },
    }],
};
```

Speaking of Heroku. PM2 provides [Heroku integration](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/integrations/heroku/).
Hope this one helps!

Comment: I want to start 3 services on 3 different port. Is it possible using above PM2 module..?

Comment: of course! All you need to do is to provide desired port into env.

Answer (score 0):

@number16BusShelter suggested a good option. But if you want to do it quick then go for the below option.

Add below code in your Procfile :

```
web: node service1.js && node service2.js && node service3.js
```

Reference: [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#define-a-procfile)

Comment: but it uses same port I want all 3 services to run on different port

Comment: You can do similar to this. https://pilot.co/blog/hosting-multiple-heroku-apps-on-a-single-domain/. Use docker, reverseproxy